# Is it possible to make complex validation on non-controler bean using Spring Validation?

Tags: spring

I like how `org.springframework.validation.Validator` is organized (providing own Errors object etc).

I would like tu use Spring's validation service to validate arguments passed to service layer methods. Is it possible out of the box? I know I can use JSR validation this way, but that only allows me to validate fields detached from the context. So is it possible out of the box, or do I have to write validtor and invoke it by hand from service layer?

Consider this bean (non practical but demonstrative)

```
public class Gender{
    boolean female=false;
    boolean male=false;
    boolean uknown=false;
}
```

and

```
public void registerGender(Gender gender){
    Errors errors=genderValidator.validate(gender);
    if(errors.hasErrors){
       throw new Exception("some exception",errors);
    }
}
```

In this example it is obvious you cannot be male female and uknown at once, genderValidator would check if one of those is true. Now I would like Spring to take care of that validation as invoking gender validator and throwing errrors on some validation failures seems like bolierplate and fits perfectly as task for a framewor.

Comment: I think you might have to do it manually or implement using AOP. AFAIK Spring has no built-in support for automatically validating arguments to beans that are not controllers.

Comment: Fair enough, but it seems that it should be no difference in implementation - after all - its all components. I have written aspect that does what I want indeed. \@Validated + \@Valid seems to be very close - all that I am missing in it is invocation of complex validators - not just plain JSR validation. That also required additional bean (that is included with framework)

Comment: "after all - its all components".. That's true, however controllers have additional logic implemented under `spring-web` which handles converting request parameters and invoking validation on annotated parameters. The latter is handled by `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(...)`.

Comment: Right, and I am wondering why is this in web module not core (in similar not exact form of course). It seems likea a general purpose mechanism to me. What do you think?

Comment: Not sure why other components don't support it in a similar fashion. That's a question for spring devs I guess :)